# How to prevent getting <uninitialized> from NSUserDefaults retrieval of an object

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to retrieve an object that I've stored.

This is my save functionality:

```
let archivedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: imageMetadata)
UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: kUserDefaultsKey)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

and then I'm retrieving the data with the following:

```
var checkDefaults : Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kUserDefaultsKey) as! Data
var newObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: checkDefaults)
var newImageMetadata : CCImageMetadata = newObject as! CCImageMetadata
```

When I inspect newObject it seems to be of type `CCImageMetadata` but when I force the cast it shows as `<uninitialized>`

[image: inspecting custom object]

Any ideas why this would be the case? It looks like it's not initialized but I'm not sure why that'd be the case

Comment: What happens if you try to `print(newImageMetadata)` does that change the `uninitialized` state?

Comment: I wonder if this is related to Swift's Definitive Initialization: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=28. This link might be outdated?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question, it's just a suggestion for an alternative to the old keyed archiver/unarchiver.

If you feel like being more modern and Swift-y you can use this extension to store `Codable` objects in the user defaults.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func decodable<T>(type: T.Type, forKey key: String) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
        guard let data = data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
    }

    func set<T>(value: T?, forKey key: String) throws where T: Encodable {
        if let value = value {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            let data = try encoder.encode(value)
            set(data, forKey: key)
        } else {
            removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

I guess you could something similar for objects `NSCoding`-compliant objects. I'm not sure if this would work, but how about:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func decodable<T>(type: T.Type, forKey key: String) throws -> T? where T: NSObject, T: NSCoding {
        guard let data = data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
        return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: T.self, from: data)
    }

    func set<T>(value: T?, forKey key: String) throws where T: NSObject, T: NSCoding {
        if let value = value {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            set(data, forKey: key)
        } else {
            removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```